# Why NavLink is not working properly and it doesn't add a parameter to the url?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I created these two buttons to take you to the login or registration page but they still take you to the /auth page without /register or /login

```
<NavLink to={`/auth/register`}><button className={styles["btn-register"]}>Zarejestruj się</button></NavLink>
<NavLink to={`/auth/login`}><button className={styles["btn-login"]}>Zaloguj się</button></NavLink>
```

Here is the path to this component

```
{ path: 'auth/:id', element: <LoginPage /> },
```

When entering the link manually everything works fine
Edit
Ok everything works fine, someone I'm doing added a second navbar in a different folder and I edited the navbar not used so nothing wanted to work

Comment: I don't see any issue with the `NavLink` code used here. How are you rendering the routes? This isn't enough code to have context for any issues. Please [edit] to include a more complete and relevant [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you.

There are possibly 2 ways to solve it. Either use exact path keyword in routes. or do as mentioned below.

```
<Route path="/auth" element="component_name">
<Route path: 'auth/:id', element: <LoginPage /> />
</Route>
```

Comment: It still doesn't work like navlink doesn't catch anything after the second /

Comment: The `Route` component hasn't any `exact` prop and I doubt nesting the route to make the path `"/auth/auth/:id"` will fix any issue the OP has.

Comment: Hey, I've used the nested routes and hence I'm mentioning it here. Else i'd not mention it here.